# Data format in soil.spec package in R

Tags: r

I would like to use the `trans` function of `soil.spec` package to transform spectra using continuum removal. But I don't understand data format of raw spectra `"raw"`

the function example is:

```
trans(raw, tr = "continuum removed", order = , gap = )
```

Could someone show me an example of `"raw"` matrix

Answer (score 2):

for continuum removal you can alternatively use the [`prospectr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prospectr/) package

```
require(prospectr)
data(NIRsoil)
```

If your spectral data is in absorbance units then:

```
crt <- continuumRemoval(X = NIRsoil$spc, type = 'A')

matplot(x = colnames(NIRsoil$spc), y = t(crt), 
        type = "l", lty = 1, 
        xlab = "Wavelengths (nm)", 
        ylab = "Absorbance (CR)",
        col = palette(gray(seq(0, 0.9, len = 25))))
```

If the spectral data is in reflectance units the `type` argument must be set to `'R'`.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say the `soil.spec` package is very weak on documentation.  But, based on this quote from one of the I/O tools,

> read.spc reads binary spectral spc-ﬁles from a folder into R. The
>   spectra can be made compatible (see details in make.comp) either to
>   the ﬁrst sample wavebands or to the standard wavebands of the ICRAF
>   spectral lab. Information from the scanning method is gathered to
>   check on spectral comparability. The default has been set to ICRAF
>   spectral bands

My suspicion is that you need to have your files in whatever "spectral spc-files" format is, assuming that is an industry standard.   Best bet may be to contact the package maintainer directly.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain continuum removal transformation on your spectra using the `soil.spec` library, proceed as follows:

1. Prepare the raw spectra table and ensure its columns contains the spectral data to be transformed. Remove all non-spectral columns and ensure that no missing values.
2. Make the column names of raw spectra table to numeric format.
3. Proceed to run the transformation as shown below

   raw.cw <- trans(raw,tr="continuum removed", order=1, gap=21)

raw.cw contains the raw spectra prior to the transformation, and the transformed spectra matrix now in your case continuum removed and the transformation method used.

To see these three objects run:

```
names(raw.cw)
```

raw.cw is an arbitrary object name assigned to the results obtained via other trans function.

Your continuum removed spectra is extracted from the results using the standard syntax as used in R system:

```
cw.spectra<-raw.cw$trans
```

We are updating the documentation of the `soil.spec` package and some of these explanations will be included as we release the next updated version which will bring additional functionalities for handling spectral data.

Kindly let me know if this helps but if you face any difficult with following this guideline to get the expected results, I will be glad to help.

Best,

Andrew

ICRAF

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, I tryed to obtain a continuum removed spectra from my data (350:2500 nm, spectral resolution 1 nm), however the result was  transformed spectra but not CR spectra (i.e. with values between 0 and 1). I used raw.cw<-trans(s,tr="continuum removed", order=0,gap=1), where "s" is a dataframe, containing 72 soil samples, having the reflectance spectrum of sample 1 in the first row. Please, can you help me to find the error? Fabio